# Minimum field in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table

I have two fields in an attribute table and I want to add a third one which will contain the minimum of these two fields.

For instance,

Field 1  Field 2 Field 3

100      50      50

20       50      20

Answer (score 7):

you could also do this:

```
min( !f1!, !f2!)
```

in field calculator, with the parser set to python